# How to establish if OpenCV frame coming in is blank (or just has time clock and camera name)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming

I have an interesting dilemma that I am not sure how to solve. I have a live video running on my application being read by OpenCV (very standard, found all over the internet):

```
# import the opencv library
import cv2
  
  
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  
while(True):
      
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()
  
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      
    # the 'q' button is set as the
    # quitting button you may use any
    # desired button of your choice
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
  
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However I have an issue where the feed is sometimes lost. Meaning that instead of seeing a video frame with something in the view all I see is a black screen with the camera clock and possibly the channel name.

[image]

I wanted to be alerted to this so that I can restart the system or send out an alert. I attempted to sum the frame contents (thinking it would be zero but this isn't the case).

```
log.warning("Frames coming in : for Camera Channel 2 : Shape " + str(np.shape(prev_frames)) + " Sum " + str(np.sum(prev_frames)) + " " + str(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))

Result:
Frames coming in : for Camera Channel 2 : Shape (1, 480, 960, 3) Sum 22581318 17:01:10
```

Is there any way to tell if the frame is in this status? Basically a dead view?

Much appreciated

Comment: *(very standard, found all over the internet)*... and wrong. I would think that counting the nonzero pixels and then finding a threshold that indicates an empty/valid frame would work. Do you have a sample of a frame from the live stream as well?

Comment: Hi,
The CV code was just to explain (and a copy paste), the final code is more complicated and not the main issue I am facing (didn't want to complicate question). To answer your question, here are some of the sum of the other cameras with live feed. Channel 2 is the dead camera shown in the image:
Channel 1 - 124 564 370 
Channel 2 - 22 581 318 
Channel 3 - 170 527 631 
Channel 4 - 32 044 568 
Channel 5 -  30 755 466 
Channel 6 - 34 125 319 
I am using np.sum, you mention counting non-zero pixels, i.e. not summing them all ?

Comment: Yes, I think if you threshold the original image and then count the nonzero pixels, you'll get a more accurate picture of how much of the image is occupied than if you sum pixel values. If it's not, and the channel/time information are always in the same place, you can just mask that area off before you count or sum the pixels. And when I said "wrong", primarily what I was saying is that the value of `frame` is never verified after reading, leading to problems like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+VideoCapture+%22-215%22+is%3Aq).

Comment: np.count_nonzero(prev_frames) for the image above results in 1378536
np.count_nonzero(prev_frames) for a camera that is generating an image results in 1355234. So similar. Its like the black portion of the image isn't seen as black or zero? That is my feeling?

Comment: No, there are only a few pixels in that image that are zero. If you convert the image to grayscale and threshold at around 40 or so, then you'll get a much more representative count. I can't tell you how to do that on a live image because I can't see what you're working with.